# Saving in gnuplot with different extensions

Tags: gnuplot

Well, I always save my works with the .gp extension. But I know that there is also another extension, the .gnu one.

What's the difference between saving with the extension .gp and with the another extension .gnu?

If there is a difference, what is the best in your opinion and why?

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: The file extension is irrelevant. You could also use `.gnuplot` or `.foobar` or whatever you like. So, just use what you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more thing: do you know if any of these saves the commands of the session?

Comment: Someone googling "gnuplot extensions" regarding output *image* extensions might end up here. In that case have a look a the different terminals (`help terminal`) for info regarding output to .png, .jpg, .pdf, .eps, etc.

Comment: You're right @Miguel and I should've added more specific tags...

Comment: You can use `save 'myfile.gp'` to save the current session (the terminal is not saved.

Comment: But does that save the history of the commands of that session, I mean, if I save the session and then work on another things with gnuplot (on another session) and then if I load the first session, will I be able to reuse a command of it (the first session)?

Comment: It doesn't save the history, so you cannot 'browse' back, but it saves all user-defined functions, variables and setting you have defined at that time.